# Nested Schema in Spark/Scala with Multiple Elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I wanted to create a predefined Schema in spark/scala so that I can read the json files accordingly.
Structure of the Schema is as below :

```
root
 |-- arrayCol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- qty: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- end: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- start: string (nullable = true)
 |-- primaryKeys: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

I was able to create the schema but I am stuck at one place where the elements have two sub elements. This is what I have tried

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val testSchema = StructType(
List(
    StructField("primaryKeys", StringType, true),
    StructField("state", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("email",ArrayType(StringType,true),true),
    StructField("id",StringType,true),
    StructField("name",StringType,true),
    StructField("id2",StringType,true),
    StructField("price",StringType,true),
    StructField("qty",StringType,true),
    StructField("window",ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
))
```

I am not able to figure out how start and end can be included inside that window element.

Comment: You didn't include any error you're encountering. But `window` is a struct, not an array, maybe this is what you're referring to as _where the elements have two sub elements_ and what is causing problems for you.

Comment: A tip for writing these, if you write the correct case class for it, you can generate the right schema using Encoders.product[T].schema

Answer (score 0):

it is a nested struct, so it should be

```
StructType(StructField("end",StringType,true), StructField("start",StringType,true))
```

btw, you can get schema from case classes as follow:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection

case class ArrayColWindow(end:String,start:String)
case class ArrayCol(id:String,email:Seq[String], qty:Long,rqty:Long,pids:Seq[String],
                        sqty:Long,id1:String,id2:String,window:ArrayColWindow, otherId:String)
    
    
case class FullArrayCols(arrayCol:Seq[ArrayCol],primarykey:String,runtime:String)
val schema =ScalaReflection.schemaFor[FullArrayCols].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured out to make it work is as under :

```
 val arrayStructureSchema = new StructType()
.add("primaryKeys",StringType,true)
.add("runtime", StringType, true)
.add("email", ArrayType(StringType))
.add("id", StringType)
.add("id1", StringType)
.add("id2", StringType)
.add("otherId", StringType)
.add("qty", StringType)
.add("rqty", StringType)
.add("sqty", StringType)
.add("window", new StructType()
    .add("end",StringType)
    .add("start",StringType))
```